# Storing Postgres data on a separate AWS EBS volume.

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have an Amazon EC2 instance running postgres. I would like to connect another EBS volume to this that is used ONLY for postgres data.  I can add the volume, but how do configure postgres so it uses the mounted ebs drive for it's data storage?

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a file system on the EBS and then mount it.   See
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html
2. Set ownership of your filesystem to postgres.
3. Use the initdb command to initialize your new space.
4. Tell postgres to use your new file system, by using the -D option to
   the postgres binary, setting the PGDATA environment variable, or by
   setting the value of data_directory in postgresql.conf

Answer (score 2):

You would edit the postgres pgdata and point it to the directory mapped to your EBS volume, as described in the thread here -

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/change-postgresql-data-directory-649911/